# How to create hard SQL request in MySQL (recursion)

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, algorithm

Sorry for my not perfect english, but I need some help.

I heard that version 5 does not support recursion in the query, but version 8 does, I also heard that you can bypass the limitation of version 5 and make a recursive query.

[There is such a table with data for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElImP.png)

```sql
CREATE TABLE `Example` (
  `id` int NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `name` varchar(512) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8_general_ci;

INSERT INTO `Example` (`id`, `parent_id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 0, 'Something 1'),
(2, 1, 'Something 2'),
(3, 2, 'Something 3'),
(4, 1, 'Something 4');
```

From this table, I have to get data in this form: This is an array of objects, inside which there are keys with table data and a datф value, which is also an array of objects

```js
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Something 1',
    parent_id: 0,
    data: [
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Something 2',
        parent_id: 1,
        data: [
          {
            id: 3,
            name: 'Something 3',
            parent_id: 2,
            data: []
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Something 4',
        parent_id: 1,
        data: []
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

Comment: *`CHARSET=utf8_general_ci`* - not exists. Should be, for example, `DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci`.

Comment: Recurse forward and calculate the level for each node. Then recurse backward from the most deep level and construct according JSON for each row posessed on currently processed level aggregating its child's nodes (if exists) JSONs. Finally return root nodes JSONs only.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete solution, but I hope someone could complete it or you can do it in a programming language after here.

```
WITH recursive cte_name AS
(
       SELECT id,
              parent_id,
              NAME,
              1 lvl
       FROM   example test
       UNION ALL
       SELECT     e.id,
                  e.parent_id,
                  e.NAME,
                  lvl+1
       FROM       cte_name c
       INNER JOIN example e
       ON         c.id = e.parent_id ), rec_tab AS
(
         SELECT   id,
                  parent_id,
                  NAME,
                  row_number() OVER (partition BY parent_id, NAME ORDER BY lvl DESC) AS path_pattern
         FROM     cte_name), path_tab as (
SELECT   id,
          group_concat(DISTINCT parent_id ORDER BY path_pattern DESC separator ' ') path
FROM     rec_tab
GROUP BY id)
select * from path_tab;
```

As you can see, path starts from 0(zero) for every root.

[image]

If someone complete solution for requested format, I would also appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- I have not seen a recursive in MySQL 5.
- `WITH RECURSIVE CTE` requires either MySQL 8 or MariaDB 10.2.
- Alternative 1:  `UNION ALL` of several queries, each reaching a different depth.  (Problem: you have to hard-code the maximum depth to check.)
- Alternative 2:  In your app, do the looping needed to simulate the recursion.